# Flex - add UI componets to mx:Button or sparks:Button

Tags: apache-flex, button

I would like have button containing other components (example:TextAreal, Image).
I have found Flexlib with CanvasButton but in Flex4 id didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think, [this](http://www.andymcintosh.com/?p=179) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answer butit's not exacly what i'm looking for. I would like combine Image and TextArea(supports bold/italic style).